# Normalization using parallel R script

Tags: r, scran

I need to implement a parallel version of an R script because on one core it takes forever to execute. The function that takes the most of time is `scran::quickCluster()` applied to an integer sparse matrix (`UMI_count`) that is `26000x66000`. The code is presented below:

```
library(scran)
library(scater)
sce <- newSCESet(countData=UMI_count)
clusters <- quickCluster(sce)
sce <- computeSumFactors(sce, cluster=clusters)
```

I did not find much on parallel versions of `quickCluster()` function, so will it actually execute in parallel if I set the number of cores to more than one? I am trying to do normalization of heterogeneous dataset with multiple cell types, that is why I am using [`quickCluster()`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/scran/inst/doc/scran.html).

And I just need to speed it up to be able to compute it.

Comment: Do you really have to use a sparse matrix? A matrix of that size with 64-bit integers is still <20GB and not have any of the annoyances of a sparse matrix.

Comment: But will it speed up quickCluster() function in any way? I can convert it to regular matrix on the cluster (that gives up to 120Gb of RAM).

Comment: I suspect it will, it's generally easier to work with normal matrices.

Answer (score 2):

The [`scran::quickCluster` method](https://rdrr.io/bioc/scran/man/quickCluster.html) has a `BPPARAM` (i.e., `BiocParallelParam`), so if one provides something like

```
clusters <- quickCluster(sce, BPPARAM=BiocParallel::MulticoreParam())
```

it will use all available cores (a specific number of cores can also be given). See [the intro doc to `BiocParallel`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/BiocParallel/inst/doc/Introduction_To_BiocParallel.pdf) for info on other options.